# How can I get the second line of text to hide and show on hover? CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have tried using text-indent but this only applies to the first line and if I use margin the text doesn't show at all, how else can I make the text show on hover? here is the code

HTML:

```
<img src=""  width="270" height="182"/>

<figcaption>
 <ul>
  <div style="top:0px; left:0px;width=270 height=182">


  <a href="">Title</a><BR>
  <a href="">Item 1</a><BR>
  <a href="">Item 2</a><BR>
  <a href="">Item 3</a><BR>
  <a href="">Item 4</a>
  </div>


 </ul>

</figcaption>
```

CSS:

```
.annotated{
position:relative;
}

.annotated img{ 
display:block;
}

.annotated ul{ 
list-style:none;
position:absolute; 
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}

.annotated div{
display:block;
padding:0 5px;
width:270px; 
line-height:15px;
position:absolute;
text-indent:-99999px; 
cursor:default;
}

.annotated div:hover { 
background:#fff;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
z-index:2; 
width:260px;
text-indent:0;

-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
       box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bKejV/1/) is a fiddle

Comment: Are you trying to have all the links show, and then "Item1" hide when you hover over the div?

Comment: I'm trying to have all the text hidden at first, and then everything show when I hover over the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide the entire caption until the user hovers over the figure, use:

```
.annotated figcaption {
    display: none;
}

.annotated:hover figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```

If you want the title to always be displayed, and the other links to display only on hover, use:

```
.annotated figcaption a {
    display: none;
}

.annotated figcaption a:first-child {
    display: inline;
}

.annotated:hover figcaption a {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that first one is perfect, I was making it way too complicated.